# Application of Bernoulli Theorem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Can we apply Bernoulli theorem to two different fluids?

I tried to visualise this problem in the following way:
Let's imagine a container having two fluids , one of some arbitrary density twice the other . Also let the height of both liquids be the same . Then will the speed of efflux of the two liquids be the same from two holes at some height equal from the base of the two fluids be the same ?

My intuition answers in negative. So I tried to use Bernoulli theorem , only to get confused .

Comment: The efllux velocity is a function of only height .

Comment: What did the Bernoulli equation tell you?

Comment: I meant  I was unable to apply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed of efflux and Bernoulli's Theorem are just converted forms of conservation of energy. Since the speed attained by two bodies after traveling same distance under same acceleration did not change, the speed of efflux also remains same for both the fluids.